# Crash code for google analytics in android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

Where should i include the following code to report uncaught exception?

```
UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(
    myTracker,                                        // Currently used Tracker.
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),      // Current default uncaught exception handler.
    context);                                         // Context of the application.

// Make myHandler the new default uncaught exception handler.
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
```

I have included these lines right after I create a tracker for my activity in onCreate() method. I get to see that the uncaught exception works and it is printed in my logcat

```
04-11 16:10:48.024: V/GAV3(13644): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (@MainActivity:onConnect:196) {main}
04-11 16:10:48.024: V/GAV3(13644): Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
04-11 16:10:48.024: V/GAV3(13644): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
04-11 16:10:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(13644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
....
```

But I dont get it in my account (property's view). My code in onCreate() to create a tracker

```
Tracker mainActivityTracker=((ADMPApplication)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER,this);
        mainActivityTracker.setScreenName("MainActivity");
        // Send a screen view.
        mainActivityTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    //    analytics.dispatchLocalHits();
        UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(mainActivityTracker,Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),this); 
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
```

I receive the notification for setScreenname(). But crash report is not reported. What is it that I'm missing? Kindly help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems this is a bug in the Google Play Services - see: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=443.
It is very unfortunate that the issue is still not fixed, you can try reverting to use GA v3.

For the record, I also observed the same issue (everything except exceptions are reported) on two of my devices that were using GPS >= 4.4.52, but weirdly not on another one having no GPS installed (in which case it simply pushed the hits as soon as they were entered).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should implement it at your app's `Application`'s class at onCreate() function

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
     Tracker currentTracker = getTracker(AppConfiguration.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
     Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = new ExceptionReporter(currentTracker,Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),this);
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

here : [What is Application class?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)